# change url hash value on a link

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-bbq

i have a url string and i am wondering how to change the order=desc part into order=asc when Iuse a link on a page?

http://localhost/en/search?city=Paris#order=desc

when i click on a link e.g.

```
<a href="#">Change order</a>
```

the url would change into

http://localhost/en/search?city=Paris#order=asc

Comment: What is the url, the url of the page or a string?

Answer (score 2):

Simply include the fragment identifier (the part after the `#`) in the link (href attribute).

```
<a href="#order=asc">Change order</a>
```